# regEx is not working while parsing through xsl

Tags: regex, xslt

hi i want to put a regex for my xml tag the tag is start with `<SV1>` here i want to put regEx for 1 . it can be any number from 0 to 1 . it is not working

i have tryed with below code.

```
<LineAmount><xsl:value-of select="SV*.[0-9].*/SV102"/></LineAmount>
```

it is not woking can some body help me.

Comment: You wrote `*.` instead of `.*`. I voted to close the question as a simple typo.

Comment: hi it's not working i tried . this in xsl and i need to fetch value at location SV1/SV102 . instead of this it can also be SV2/SV201 or SV3/SV301 .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use regular expression matching in XSLT then you need to use at least XSLT 2.0 (like for instance with an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime) and for element names (or node names in general) you need to use a predicate that tests the name e.g.

```
<xsl:value-of select="*[matches(local-name(), 'SV[0-9]')]/SV102"/>
```

selects `SV102` with a parent of the name `SV0`, `SV1`, `SV2`, `SV3` and so on.